# Ruby on Rails: combobox is showing id and not the name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, combobox

I got the code

```
<%= f.select :wahl1, options_for_select(@berufs) %>
```

and im getting id´s or smth `#<Beruf:0x45ed8e8>` instead of the name of @berufs in the combobox

Comment: What is contained in `@berufs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options_for_select` expects a simple array or hash of keys and values. Yet you are passing it a collection of models.

What you want is `options_from_collection_for_select`, for example:

```
= f.select :wahl1, options_from_collection_for_select(@berufs, 'id', 'name')
```